# Getting the Request Env in a worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, resque, mixpanel

I'm using the [Mixpanel Gem](https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel) for server side event tracking. I chose to use the [Resque implementation](https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel#how-to-track-events-using-resque-and-rails). As you can see in the example, in the  `UsersController`, you have to pass the `env` as a hash because *"Trying to pass request.env to Resque is going to fail (it chokes when trying to convert it to JSON)"*. This works but if you refactor that code into the model, then you have to generate the env variable in the controller before passing it to queue in the model, which just seems wrong.

I've written a method that generates it in the `ApplicationController`, but I'm measuring so many events that I'm passing it through the model so many times it just doesn't make sense. Is there a way to get the `request` variable in the worker instead of passing it through to the worker?

Comment: I fail to see how this is wrong. The request object represents an execution environment that is only available to the controller that handles the request ; workers, by design, perform their job outside of the request's lifecycle. One way or another, you'll have to pass the required env parameters when starting the job...

Comment: Just feels wrong because i'm using it so many times... If this is ok to do I'll continue to do it. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 'passing it through the model' ?

Comment: As in placing `Resque.enqueue MixpanelTrackEventJob, 'Sign up', { :invited => params[:invited] }, env` in the model, would be great if I could place it in an `after_create` in the model. Thanks.

Comment: I think a different refactoring strategy is in order. Thanks for the help guys.